# Knex query builder tool's update() query

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I'm using knex query builder and SQL Server.

So have an usecase where I dont want `select @@rowcount` to be appended to `update()`.

This is the query using knex:

```
let updateQuery = knex('details').where('id', studentId).andWhere({name: Name}).update({
'value': Value,
'updated_at': new Date()});
```

SQL generated by qb :

```sql
update [details] 
set [value] = ?, [updated_at] = ? where [id] = ? and [name] = ?; select @@rowcount
```

So, what changes should I do so that it doesn't append `select @@rowcount`?

Comment: Why is it an "issue" that it does this?

Comment: Sorry,  not an issue!  Just updated the question.

Comment: So why does it matter than it does append `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: So I'm trying to implement upsert something like this.  update table1 
set name = 'val2', itemname = 'val3', itemcatName = 'val4', itemQty = 'val5'
where id = 'val1'
if @@ROWCOUNT= 0
insert into table1(id, name)
values('val1', 'val2')

Comment: Seems like what you're asking, and what you want to do are 2 completely different things.

Comment: So far,  I've implemented like this..  upsertQuery = knex. raw('? IF @@rowcount=0 ?', [updateQ,  insertQ]). since updatequery has "select @@rowcount" it fails when inserting the rows

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do to prevent `.update()` from creating that.

Writing knex extension/plugin that uses `knex.raw` to generate the query sounds like a correct option for you. Docs for extend are missing linking so they can be found around this location http://knexjs.org/#Builder-queryContext

Comment: Hey Mikael,  if I use returning('id') to the query,  update() will not add select @@rowcount part right?  Instead it inserts an output clause ! Is that approach correct?

Comment: yes, that seems to drop the @@rowcount and add `output` clause.